# R count how many elements in a group occur in a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a vector and a dataframe that look like below:

```
class.interest <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df <- data.frame("Subject" = c(rep("A",3), rep("B",3), rep("C",5), "D", "E"),
                 "Class" = c("a", "b", "f", "b", "b", "e", "a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "c", "f"))
```

What I'd like to do is count how many times the elements in `class.interest` appear for each `Subject` in `df`. I hope to get something like this as a result:

```
# of occurrences    count    count.from.subject
0                   1        E
1                   1        D
2                   2        A,B
3                   0        NA
4                   1        C
5                   0        NA
```

To explain this output further,

the first column (`# of occurences`) just refers to how many times the elements in `class.interest` can possibly appear for each `Subject` (so it'll always be a list of integers between zero and the length of `class.interest` vector)

the second column (`count`) was counted like this:

For subject `A`, there are 3 entries in `Class`, but only two elements in `class.interest` (exluding `f`). For subject `B`, there are two elements (there are 3 entries in the data frame for `B`, but `"b"` occurs twice). In the same way, subject `C` has 4 elements, `D` has 1 element and `E` has none.

So I'm just putting what I described above into the output now - for instance, only subject `E` did not have any of the elements in `class.interest`, hence the first row of output. Or both subject `A` and `B` had two elements in `class.interest`, third row of `count` becomes 2.

Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to count something this way?

+++ edit:

Thanks for all the wonderful suggestions! Would it also be possible to preserve the information about `Class` rather than just counting the frequencies using `summarise`? This would make the output much larger and I'm not sure what a good format would be for rows that have `count` higher than 1, maybe something like below?

```
# of occurrences    count    count.from.subject       count.class
0                   1        E                        NA
1                   1        D                        c
2                   2        A                        a,b
2                   2        B                        b,e 
3                   0        NA                       NA
4                   1        C                        a,b,c,e
5                   0        NA                       NA
```

Comment: As a start, look at `df |> group_by(Subject) |> distinct(Class) |> summarize(count = length(Class[Class != "f"]))`. This gets the data you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>% filter(Class != "f") %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  summarise(`# of occurrences` = n_distinct(Class)) %>% 
  group_by(`# of occurrences`) %>% 
  summarise(count = length(Subject), 
            count.from.subject = paste(Subject, collapse = ","))
```

---

#### Edit:

You can use also use `mutate` with `group_by` instead of `summarise`, which will append the same value to each element in the group:
(with complete you can extend the missing values)

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(Class = na_if(Class, "f")) %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  summarise(`# of occurrences` = n_distinct(na.omit(Class)), 
            count.class = na_if(paste(sort(unique(na.omit(Class))), collapse = ","), "")) %>% 
  group_by(`# of occurrences`) %>% 
  mutate(count = n()) %>% ungroup() %>% 
  complete(`# of occurrences` = 0:5, fill = list(count = 0)) %>% 
  transmute(`# of occurrences`, count, count.from.subject = Subject, count.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm trying to figure out if I can preserve the information on `Class` also (updated question above). I figured out that I could use `mutate` intsead of `summarise` in your third line of code to keep the `Class` information but the `length` doesn't work since there's the extra `Class` column.

Comment: Your edit clarified the question, I've updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
df %>%
  distinct() %>%
  left_join(data.frame(Class= class.interest, count = 1)) %>%
  group_by(Subject) %>%
  summarise(count=sum(count, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
  group_by(count) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), Subject=toString(Subject))%>%
  complete(count = 0:5, fill=list(n = 0))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  count     n Subject
  <dbl> <int> <chr>  
1     0     1 E      
2     1     1 D      
3     2     2 A, B   
4     3     0 NA     
5     4     1 C      
6     5     0 NA
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'm trying to figure out if I can preserve the information on Class also (updated question above). I was able to get something like this by editing the `summarise` function in your fifth line to `mutate`, then used `filter(Class %in% class.interest)` to filter out `Class` that I didn't want, but I'm having trouble how to count those numbers (like you did with `n=n()` now that there's the extra `Class` column)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
left_join(
  tibble(num_occurrence = 0:length(class.interest)),
  group_by(df, Subject) %>% 
  summarize(num_occurrence = sum(unique(Class) %in% class.interest)) %>% 
  group_by(num_occurrence) %>% 
  summarize(count = n(), count.from_subject = toString(c(Subject)))
  ) %>% mutate(count = ifelse(is.na(count), 0, count))
```

Output:

```
  num_occurrence count count.from_subject
           <int> <dbl> <chr>             
1              0     1 E                 
2              1     1 D                 
3              2     2 A, B              
4              3     0 NA                
5              4     1 C                 
6              5     0 NA
```